# Replace strings via regexp by groups in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I would like to replace many terms using regexp with a single call, is it possible? In the example below I want to replace all *spaces* and *ö* chars to *_* and *-* respectively.

> Pattern: `( +)|(ö+)`
>
> Source string: `Abc dfö/ab.ai dois ö`
>
> Replace pattern: `$1_$2-`
>
> Current result: `Abc _-df_ö-/ab.ai _-dois _-_ö-`
>
> Expected result: `Abc_df-/ab.ai_dois_-`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback function to check which group "worked" and replace accordingly:

```js
var re = /( +)|(ö+)/g; 
var str = 'Abc dfö/ab.ai dois ö';
var result = str.replace(re, function (m, g1, g2) {
    return g1 ? "_" : "-";
});
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

The second argument in [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a function.

> A function to be invoked to create the new substring (to put in place of the substring received from parameter *#1*).

See more details on the callback  function parameters in the [*Specifying a function as a parameter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) section.

**UPDATE**

You may map the symbols (since you are searching for single symbols) to the replacement symbols, and specify them all in 1 regex. Then, in the callback function, you can get the necessary value using the first character from the matched text.

```js
var rx = / +|ö+|ë+|ü+/g;
str = "Abc dfö/ab.ai dois ööö üüü";
console.log(str);
map = { 
    " ": "_", 
    "ö": "-", 
    "ü": "+", 
    "ë": "^"
};
result = str.replace(rx, function (match) {
    return map[match[0]]; }
);
console.log(result);
// Abc dfö/ab.ai dois ööö üüü => Abc_df-/ab.ai_dois_-_+
```

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev but I need a solution more generic in case of I have for example `/( +)|(ö+)|(ä+)|(ë+)|(ü+)|(etc...+)/g`

Comment: XY problem? That is not good. Anyway, you will have 2 choices: either use the callback specifying the necessary amount of capturing groups, or use chained `replace()` methods. You cannot specify multiple *literal* replacements in the replacement pattern.

Comment: yes @stribizhev... I was trying to avoid that approach so looks like that will be the way. thanks and upped :)

Comment: one could change the OR connected pattern in a way that its remaining capturing group can be used as key of a map of surrogate/replacement characters.    
```    var
      regX = /( |ö)+/g,
      str  = "Abc dfö/ab.ai dois ö",
    
      map  = {
        " ": "_",
        "ö": "-",
      },
    
      result = str.replace(regX, function (match, $1) {
        return map[$1];
      })
    ;
    console.log("str, result : ", str, result);```